# Iterate through list in bash and run multiple grep commands

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to iterate through a list and grep for the items, then use awk to pull out important information from each grep result. (This is the way I thought to do it, but awk and grep aren't necessary if there is a better way).

The input file contains a number of lines that looks similar to this:

```
chr1    12345   .   A   G   3e-12   .   AB=0;ABP=0;AC=0;AF=0;AN=2;AO=2;CIGAR=1X;
```

I have a number of locations that should match some part of the second column.

```
locList="123, 789"
```

And for each matching location I would like to get the information from columns 4 and 5 and write them to an output file with the corresponding location.

So the output for the above list should be:

```
123 A G
```

Something like this is what I'm thinking:

```
for i in locList; do
    grep i inputFile.txt | awk '{print $2,$4,$5}'
done
```

Comment: What does your attempt output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v locList='123|789' '$2~"^("locList")" {print $2,$4,$5}' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
locList='123, 789'
awk -v locList="^(${locList//, /|})" '$2~locList {print $2,$4,$5}' file
```

or whatever other permutation you like. The point is you don't need a loop at all - just create a regexp from the list of numbers in locList and test that regexp once.

Answer (score 4):

Invoking grep/awk once per location will be highly inefficient. You want to invoke a single command that will do your parsing. For example, awk:

```
awk -v locList="12345 789" '
    BEGIN {
        # parse the location list, and create an array where
        # the locations are the array indexes
        n = split(locList, a)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) locations[a[i]] = 1
    }
    $2 in locations {print $2, $4, $5}
' file
```

---

**revised requirements**

```
awk -v locList="123 789" '
    BEGIN { n = split(locList, patterns) }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            if ($2 ~ "^" patterns[i]) {
                print $2, $4, $5
                break
            }
        }
    }
' file
```

The `~` operator is the regular expression matching operator.

That will output `12345 A G` from your sample input. If you just want to output `123 A G` then print `patterns[i]` instead of `$2`.

Comment: This works really well. The one problem which is probably because I was a bit unclear is that I would like to have `123` in the locList and have it match anything that starts with `123`. So it should match `1234` or `12345`. I tried adding a wildcard after `locations[a[i]]` but doesn't work. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do :

```
locList="123 789"
for i in $locList; do awk -vvar=$i '$2 ~ var{print $4, $5}' file; done
```